# Regex in Pattern attribute on input type number

Tags: regex, html

I have an

> input type="number"

I am trying to limit input so that only 2 digits can be entered, eg. 10, 25, 83, and so on.

I have tried

> maxlength="2"

and

> pattern="[0-9]{2}"

but neither work.

I have already removed the ability to enter letters or any other characters.  I only want numeric input.

Can anyone help?

It is Chrome that is causing me issues.

Thanks!

To limit to only numeric input I have :

```
function isNumericKey(e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How are you validating the data to make sure that only numbers can be entered?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like

```
<input type="number" min="10" step="1" max="99">
```

should do the job for you. However, the `<input type="text" pattern="\d{2}">` should work as well.

Comment: I already have the min and max set to my limits (sorry I should have mentioned that), problem is that a user can manually enter as many digits as they want...

Comment: A user always can (and should be allowed to) enter what he wants. The input then is simply considered **invalid** - which is used to feedback the user - and prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: This input field is used for the user to enter their age, I don't think its unreasonable that the limit gets set to a max of 2 digits.